# Склонение названий

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, как правильно написать: "мероприятия пройдут на улице *Советской*" или "на улице *Советская*"?

Answer (score 4):

Начнем с того, что разберемся с порядком слов. Если название представляет собой определение несогласованное (обычно форма отвечает на вопрос кого? чья? чего?), то название должно начинаться со слова улица (переулок, проспект и т.д.). Если же согласованное (улица - какая?), то название начинается с собственно названия, а "улица" идёт после.

Итак, в нашем случае правильно: **Советская улица**. В такой форме варианта "на Советская улице" просто невозможно представить. И у вас должно быть "мероприятия пройдут на Советской улице". В ислючительных случаях возможна инверсия, т.е. перестановка слов "улица" и "Советкая". Но на согласованность это не должно влиять (это нарушило бы основы грамматики русского языка): "На улице Советской".

Вариант же "на улице Советская" проистекает, видимо, из канцелярита. Подобные конструкции ещё можно до какой-то степени оправдать, если речь идёт о военных сводках, когда однозначность подчас важнее грамотности, но в мирной жизни, имхо, они не имеют права на существование.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: на улице Советской! Названия улиц склоняются вместе с родовым словом. Исключения составляют составные названия (на улице Большая Песочная) и названия, не совпадающие в роде со словом улица (на улице Восход).

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, подходят оба варианта. В первом случае "улице Советской" согласовано как словосочетание, а во втором название улицы - имя собственное, в именительном падеже и просто берётся в кавычки. Так что на ваше усмотрение.
 - Мероприятия пройдут на улице Советской.
 - Мероприятия пройдут на улице "Советская".